# Proportional Editing and Laptop Problem

Tags: mesh, transforms, edit-mode

I am using blender 2.7 and the laptop mandates the "Emulated Numpad." Upon attempting to use "Proportional Editing" in a "Bound" within the UV Editor while using projection process, I cannot use "Proportional Editing" while the attempt to grab with <kbd>G</kbd>. The attempt simply moves the entire "Bound." The only way I have been able to even move a vertex of the bound is to disable proportional editing. Any ideas? I have tried every imaginable hotkey combination.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac laptop you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and scroll (two finger gesture) up or down.

Answer (score 2):

Proportional editing effects all items within a sphere of influence. If the sphere is very large then everything appears to move the same amount.

The two standard methods of adjusting this size are mouse scroll wheel and <kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd>. For a laptop there is also a trackpad pan setup, I believe apple trackpads do panning with a two finger swipe.

If you still have trouble you can modify this shortcut yourself, you can find it by going to the [user preferences->Input](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Input), down the bottom of the list there is a group called 'Transform Modal Map' expand that and you will find Increase Proportional Influence and Decrease Proportional Influence for both keyboard and mouse, you can change these to any key combination that works for you.

[image]

Comment: Oddly, Proportional Editing works fine until I setup a projection to the UV Editor? The models mesh moves fine in edit mode until I select the models head area after having seamed the models head and selected all the head faces and then unwrapping! After having unwrapped the head area all appears fine in the uv map and the bounds appear fine while scale, rotate work fine for rough placement before I attempt proportional editing for a closer fit, however, the G key moves the entire bound even while the proportional incrementation numbers reflect a radius size change with PGUP/PGDN..any ideas?

Comment: The radius size may change but is it small enough to see the circle of influence? Is it less than 1.0?

Comment: On my Mac, you emulate Page Up and Page Down with fn + Up/Down arrows.  Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, Use Pageup or Pagedown after pressing G until the you see circle comming up and move track pad pointer to adjust the required modfication